# erlang parse string to data types using regex

Tags: regex, erlang

I'm trying to make a parser in erlang, in hope to recognize data types inside a string. After searching, I couldnt find any existed problem as mine:

- original string:  `atom1,"string2,,\"\",",{tuple3, "s pa ces \"", {[test]},"_#",test},<<"binary4\",,>>">>, #{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}}, #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} , <<300:16>>`
- string that is need to be parsed: `"atom1,\"string2,,\\\"\\\",\",{tuple3, \"s pa ces \\\"\", {[test]},\"_#\",test},<<\"binary4\\\",,>>\">>, #{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}}, #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} , <<300:16>>"`
- Expected Ouput:

  ```
  + number of params: 7
  + value ------> type"
      - atom1 ------> Atom
      - "string2,,\"\"," ------> String
      - {tuple3, "s pa ces \"", {[test]},"_#",test} ------> Tuple
      - <<"binary4\",,>>">> ------> Binary
      - #{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}} ------> Map
      - #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} ------> Record
      - <<300:16>> ------> Binary
  ```

But my current code doesnt work as expected, here it is:

```
comma_parser(Params) ->
{ok, R} = re:compile("(\".*?\"|[^\",\\s]+)(?=\\s*,|\\s*$)"),
{match, Matches} = re:run(Params, R, [{capture, [1], list}, global]),
?DEBUG("truonggv1 - comma_parser: Matches: ~p~n", [Matches]),
[M || [M] <- Matches].
```

Current Output:

```
  + number of params: 14
  + value ------> type
    - atom1 ------> Atom
    - "string2,,\"\" ------> String
    - ",{tuple3, "s pa ces \"" ------> String
    - {[test]} ------> Tuple
    - "_#" ------> String
    - test} ------> Atom
    - "binary4\" ------> String
    - >> ------> Atom
    - #{map5=>5 ------> Map
    - element=>{e1 ------> Atom
    - e2}} ------> Atom
    - 1 ------> Atom
    - 2} ------> Atom
    - <<300:16>> ------> Binary
```

Does anyone know how to correct this please ?

update my codes with Params is the "string that is need to be parsed" that I have noted above:

```
check_params_by_comma(Params) ->
  case string:str(Params, ",") of
     0 ->
       Result = Params;
     1 ->
       Result = "param starts with character ',' ~n";
     _Comma_Pos ->
       Parse_String = comma_parser(Params),
       Result = "number of params: " ++ integer_to_list(length(Parse_String))
                ++ "\n\n\r\t value ------> type \n\r"
                ++ "\t*********************\n\r"
                ++ ["\t" ++ X ++ " ------> " ++ check_type(X) ++ "\n\r"|| X <- Parse_String]
  end,
  Result.

check_type(X) ->
  Binary = string:str(X, "<<"),
  String = string:str(X, "\""),
  Tuple = string:str(X, "{"),
  List = string:str(X, "["),
  Map = string:str(X, "#{"),
  case X of
    _ when 1 == Binary -> "Binary";
    _ when 1 == String -> "String";
    _ when 1 == Tuple -> "Tuple";
    _ when 1 == List -> "List";
    _ when 1 == Map -> "Map";
    _ -> "Atom"
  end.

comma_parser(Params) ->
  {ok, R} = re:compile("(\".*?\"|[^\",\\s]+)(?=\\s*,|\\s*$)"),
  {match, Matches} = re:run(Params, R, [{capture, [1], list}, global]),
  [M || [M] <- Matches].
```

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Comment: @Dogbert : I have updated my codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're trying to achieve, but let me tell you what I did with your input and let's see if that helps you at all.
Your situation seemed to be desperately calling for [erl_scan:string](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/erl_scan.html?i=8&search=erl_scan#string/1) and [erl_parse:parse_exprs](http://erldocs.com/current/stdlib/erl_parse.html?i=0&search=erl_parse:parse_expr#parse_exprs/1), so that's the first thing I tried.

This was my original version of the parsing:

```
-module(x).

-export([test/0, check_params_by_comma/1]).

test() ->
  Input =
    "atom1,\"string2,,\\\"\\\",\",{tuple3, \"s pa ces \\\"\", "
    "{[test]},\"_#\",test},<<\"binary4\\\",,>>\">>, "
    "#{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}}, #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} , <<300:16>>",
  io:format("~p~n", [check_params_by_comma(Input)]).

check_params_by_comma(Params) ->
  {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(Params ++ "."),
  {ok, Exprs} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens),
  Exprs.
```

Of course that was not all, since you wanted a different kind of output, but we were almost there. Copying the presentation code from your original question, I had to use [erl_prettypr:format/1](http://erldocs.com/current/syntax_tools/erl_prettypr.html?i=3&search=erl_prett#format/1) to render the terms and I ended up with something like:

```
-module(x).

-export([test/0, check_params_by_comma/1]).

test() ->
  Input =
    "atom1,\"string2,,\\\"\\\",\",{tuple3, \"s pa ces \\\"\", "
    "{[test]},\"_#\",test},<<\"binary4\\\",,>>\">>, "
    "#{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}}, #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} , <<300:16>>",
  io:format("~s~n", [check_params_by_comma(Input)]).

check_params_by_comma(Params) ->
  Parse_String = comma_parser(Params),
  "number of params: " ++ integer_to_list(length(Parse_String))
  ++ "\n\n\r\t value ------> type \n\r"
  ++ "\t*********************\n\r"
  ++ ["\t" ++ erl_prettypr:format(X) ++ " ------> " ++ check_type(X) ++ "\n\r"|| X <- Parse_String].

comma_parser(Params) ->
  {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(Params ++ "."),
  {ok, Exprs} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens),
  Exprs.

check_type({Type, _, _}) -> atom_to_list(Type);
check_type({Type, _, _, _}) -> atom_to_list(Type).
```

I think this should be enough to solve your problem but, as a bonus track, let me refactor this a bit using iolists to obtain almost exactly what the expected output required:

```
-module(x).

-export([test/0, check_params_by_comma/1]).

test() ->
  Input =
    "atom1,\"string2,,\\\"\\\",\",{tuple3, \"s pa ces \\\"\", "
    "{[test]},\"_#\",test},<<\"binary4\\\",,>>\">>, "
    "#{map5=>5, element=>{e1,e2}}, #record6{r1 = 1, r2 = 2} , <<300:16>>",
  io:format("~s~n", [check_params_by_comma(Input)]).

check_params_by_comma(Params) ->
  {ok, Tokens, _} = erl_scan:string(Params ++ "."),
  {ok, Exprs} = erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens),
  [
    io_lib:format("+ number of params: ~p~n", [length(Exprs)]),
    "+ value ------> type \n"
  | lists:map(fun format_expr/1, Exprs)
  ].

format_expr(Expr) ->
  io_lib:format(
    "\t- ~s ------> ~s~n",
    [erl_prettypr:format(Expr), string:titlecase(type(Expr))]
  ).

%% or you can do type(Expr) -> atom_to_list(hd(tuple_to_list(Expr))).
type({Type, _, _}) -> atom_to_list(Type);
type({Type, _, _, _}) -> atom_to_list(Type).
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you for your help, I followed your instruction and it seemed that your suggested parser:  `"erl_parse:parse_exprs(Tokens)"` was ok to parse the atom, integer, string, etc., but couldnt parse tuple, binary and list.

I am now back at the regex to try to parse the string, which is: `"(\".*?\"|[^\",\\s]+)(?=\\s*,|\\s*$)"`

Comment: @zoro that’s certainly strange since I run the test/0 function on my console and it printed out the exact expected output from your original post. What is the error you see?

Comment: yeaahh, you're my savior !!
I didnt recognize the power of the functions: `[erl_prettypr:format(Expr), string:titlecase(type(Expr))]` and wrongly implemented them.
Again, thank you so much !!